# Plotting real and imaginary parts of discrete function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to figure out how to plot the discrete function
*y*[*n*] = *x*[*n*-5] / (1 + *x*[*n*]).
Any help in figuring out the correct syntax is appreciated.

Comment: As a side note: if you're new to MATLAB, I suggest going through some [tutorials](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/launchpad.html), so that you get more familiar with the language.

Comment: By the way, what does this question has to do with plotting real and imaginary parts?

Comment: Read the tutorials. You have not yet even learned how to index in matlab, as square brackets do not apply here.

Comment: @woodchips it's just the definition of the function, mistakenly formatted as code. Reformatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your eq is equivalent to:

```
y[n+5] = (x[n])/(1+x[n+5])
```

I'll plot the latter over some range (change if needed):

```
lower_limit=-10
upper_limit=10
N=100;

x=linspace(lower_limit,upper_limit,N);
y=x(1:end-5)./(1-x(6:end));

plot(x(6:end),y)
```

[image]